# What format does python read Javascript arrays?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I sending parameters to a python script that is acting as my API. One of the params is a Javascript array. When logged in python is shows up as the first index in the array.

Here is my get request using Angular JS:

```
    $http.get(
        apiBase + '/deals/timeline', {
            params: {
                api_key: $scope.settings.apiKey,
                start_date: startDate,
                interval: interval,
                amount: amount,
                fieldKeys: $scope.settings.fieldKeys
            }
        })
```

Here is my python code:
    import config
    import json
    import requests

```
def api_deals_timeline(params):
    start_date = params.get('start_date')
    interval = params.get('interval')
    amount = params.get('amount')
    field_key = params.get('field_key')

    print(field_key)

    r = requests.get('url.com/?something={}&somelse={}'.format(start_date, interval))

    if r.status_code == 200:
        return json.loads(r.text)['data']
    else:
        return None
```

Here is the print statement for field_key in my apache logs:

> [Thu Aug 14 16:23:56 2014] [error] [u'add_time', u'won_time', u'lost_time', None]

AND here is the console.log for $scope.settings.fieldKeys:

> ["lost", "won", "new"]

Comment: something else is clearly happening for `lost` to become `lost_time`.  also, if this is truly just a list, HTTP already supports sending the same parameter multiple times.

Comment: I wish I had checked back here, missed this comment. I actually figured this out after trial and error. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In JavaScript, you need to send this list as JSON

```
JSON.stringify($scope.settings.fieldKeys);
```

In python, you need convert the field_key javascript array to a python list. The json library can help you out with this.

```
json.loads(field_key)
```